# IF Exists, Update. Else Insert. Connection Time Out Error

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, insert

The problem of my code is that I can insert properly into database, but if it will update, the 
connection times out. So to clarify my problem, My INSERT code works but the UPDATE doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
  Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim strConnString As String = DataSource.ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()

            Dim base64String = TextArea1.Value
            Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
            Dim ImageTypeDataOfImage As New SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.Image)
            ImageTypeDataOfImage.Value = imageBytes


            Dim SQLStr As String
            SQLStr = " IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage]   where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "' and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "')  " & _
                     " UPDATE [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage] SET PatImage= @Data where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "' and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "'  " & _
                     " else INSERT INTO [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage](HospNum,IDNum, DoctorID, PatImage , FileType, FileName, TransDATE) VALUES ('" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "','" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "', '" & Session.Item("DoctorID") & "', @Data, '" & lblHeader.Text & "', 'PatientPhoto' ,  GETDATE()) "

            cmd.CommandText = SQLStr
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageTypeDataOfImage)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: There's a lock over the row?

Comment: What do you mean There's a lock? Pls expound im kinda new at this.

Comment: This looks vulnerable to SQL Injection

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not `COMMIT`ing or `ROLLBACK`ing you transactions.

that means, your previous session still holds a lock over the rows , you attempt to update, though you close the connection. So, next time, when a update is received for the same record, the database identifies that, there is another session which hold a lock over this record, so unless it is released no more updates or deletes can be performed over it.. Also, that would wait indefinitely, that caused your timeouts.

Whereas , every `INSERT` will be a new entry and hence, the previous. Row level locks doesn't impact them. Try to kill all those sessions, with help of your DBA and include COMMIT in your code, before you close the connection.

[The Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx) has some examples to show how to COMMIT tansactions.

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

Dim strConnString As String = DataSource.ConnectionString
Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim base64String = TextArea1.Value
    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
    Dim ImageTypeDataOfImage As New SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.Image)
    ImageTypeDataOfImage.Value = imageBytes

    Dim transaction As SqlTransaction

    transaction = con.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction");

    Dim SQLStr As String
    SQLStr = " IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage]   where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "' and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "')  " & _
             " UPDATE [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage] SET PatImage= @Data where HospNum='" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "' and IDNum='" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "' and FileType= '" & lblHeader.Text & "'  " & _
             " else INSERT INTO [Patient_Data].[dbo].[tbPatientImage]

(HospNum,IDNum, DoctorID, PatImage , FileType, FileName, TransDATE) VALUES ('" & Session.Item("HospNum") & "','" & Session.Item("IDNum") & "', '" & Session.Item("DoctorID") & "', @Data, '" & lblHeader.Text & "', 'PatientPhoto' ,  GETDATE()) "

            cmd.CommandText = SQLStr
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageTypeDataOfImage)
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.Transaction = transaction
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            transaction.Commit()

            con.Close()

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have a sample code for that sir? I will use sqltransaction.commit?

Comment: I added documentation reference. kindly check the same.

Comment: hello. Im having a trouble placing my code. Can you edit my code sir and paste it here?

Comment: i've added your code to my code sir but the error connection timeout still occurs.

Comment: The existing locks has to be removed.. Hope this [link](http://www.exacthelp.com/2012/08/how-to-release-or-remove-lock-on-table.html) helps. Our new code, just avoids future locks.

Comment: is it safe to use the 'KILL'? Will it affect other data in the database?

Comment: No, KILL only the process ids that you see in the locked objects list.. That will not affect other data.

Comment: hello. I already used the KILL and removed the locked data. But after deleting it and if I will insert again, it locks again the data and I still cannot update @Maheswaran

Comment: You commit after your insert?

Comment: yes. But, after inserting and if i will select query again, there will be a locked data that will be displayed.

Comment: its like the sql commit has nothing to do with the row locks?

Comment: How are you attempting to commit. Following a INSERT/UPDATE, do a commit immediately, in the same session... You will not see a rowlock.

Comment: It's weird. Some data, i can insert then update. but SOME data i can only insert once. Gaaa

Comment: I wish I could have my hands on your machine. hard to guess wht is happening.. :(

Comment: been stuck here for 2 days. sigh

Comment: just a few, less than 1k. And i am only updating 1 data at a time. Even if i hardcode a query in sql server, it does not update, it just loads. But the other data i can update. I dont understand why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61252/discussion-between-maheswaran-ravisankar-and-dale).